# Session Variable behaving different on Visual Studio and Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want a certain segment of code to be executed only once per session, so if the user navigates to the page containing this code while within the same session, I don't want this segment to be executed. The code lives in a default page that is called right after login, and user can navigate to this default page from other pages.

My Solution:

```
if (Session["MySessionName"] == null && ConditionTwo) //initially MySessionName won't exist so the if condition resolves to true
{
    //Assign Value to MySessionName so the if condition resolves to false next time
    Session["MySessionName"] = "MySessionValue";
    //Do Something
}
```

My Problem:

This works fine on visual studio, after deploying to test server this solution doesn't seem to work all the time. If I log out and log back in, the condition `Session["MySessionName"] == null` returns `false` and the code segment won't be executed. However if I close the browser, reopen, and log in, it works fine. I have checked if the logout did a proper session dispose and it does.

I also tried,

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["MySessionName"] = "MySessionValue"; 
//and 
Session.Add("MysessionName", true);
```

but result was the same.

Comment: Do you want this to happen for every new _session_, or every _authentication_? Because those are different things. Sessions can persist between authentications (login/logout)

Comment: I want it to happen for every authentication, basically this segment needs to be executed once per every login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using forms authentication, you need to call `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`.

In addition, on logout you need to call `Context.Session.Abandon()` to terminate the current session.

I also make sure that I always explicitly clear any sensitive or user-related values from the session state prior to abandoning the session.

Comment: Thanks all, your answer and Jon Adams comment led me to the right solution, I added the Session Variable to the authentication module so that it would be abandoned by the log out process which solved my issue.